# Show that $E\left[\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathrm{1}_{A_n}\right]= \sum_{n=1}^\infty P(A_n)$ without using Fubini or Beppo-levi?

Tags: probability-theory

Show that $E\left\{\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathrm{1}_{A_n}\right\}= \sum_{n=1}^\infty P(A_n)$ where $(A_n)_{n \ge 0}$ is any sequence of events without using Fubini theorem or the  Beppo-levi.

This is problem 5.19 in Chapter 5 of Probability essentials and the aforementioned tools are developed only later in Chapter 9 of the book. Do I have to replicate the proof of the Beppo-levi for this particular case or is there a better way to show this using elementary methods and without any heavy machinery.

Thanks

Comment: What is definition of $E$ in that book?  Perhaps you have to use that.  For example, if E is defined as the sup of something about simple functions, use that.

Comment: $E[X]=\sum_{\omega} X(\omega)p_{\omega}$ where X lives on a countable space $\Omega$

Comment: Countable space.  That means, you do not need to know about integrals (Fubini, Beppo Levi), just use things about series.  Like: nonnegative series can be rearranged.

Comment: perfect, thank you, I will write the answer based on your hint